# How do I link to a pdf in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, pdf

The code below contains a hyperlink that causes a spring-generated pdf from the server to be loaded in a new browser window when a user clicks on the link.  The problem is that some users have pop-ups blocked in their browsers.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order for the pdf to open IN THE SAME BROWSER WINDOW when a user clicks on the link?**  Note that this pdf is generated by a spring controller.

Here is the html:

```
    <p><a ng-click="getPdf()">Show PDF</a></p>
```

And here is the Angular controller code:

```
angular.module('message', ['auth']).controller('message', function($scope, $http, $sce, auth) {

    $scope.authenticated = function() {
        return auth.authenticated;
    }

    $scope.getPdf = function(){
          $http.get('/api/some-pdfr', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
          .success(function (data) {
            var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL);
          });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.open` supports a second parameter, windowName. You can set this to `"_self"` to open the URL in the same window.

```
window.open(fileURL, "_self");
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for more information.

A better way might be to make the directive update the links href to the correct url before it navigates. That would let you use _blank as the target and open it in a new tab/window.

Comment: The syntax that worked is `window.open(fileURL, `_self`);`.  Thank you and +1 for a quick response.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `window.open`, you need to provide the user with a link to click on whose href is `fileUrl`. You can either do this by generating the PDF before the user clicks on the link, or by providing them with a separate link after the PDF has been generated.